# AWS/EC2 ubuntu and ssh for users other than ubuntu

Tags: server, ssh, amazon-ec2

Ubuntu on EC2 creates a user ubuntu by default. I can set up SSH keys with PuTTY and login in just fine. I've created two more logins but cannot use same PuTTY configuration to get in.
I've dug around quite a bit and changed /etc/ssh/ssh_config files and restarted but it doesn't seem to help.
I'm guessing anyone else using AWS image may have encountered this same scenario.
Thanks,
Craig
this is ubuntu 3.13.0-48-generic

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any special ssh elastic cloud compute sauce! Rather, each newly created user needs a separate ssh directory and authorized key file.

First, from you EC2 server, switch to your newly create user account ('foo' in this example):

```
    su foo
```

Next, create an SSH directory for foo and set permissions:

```
    mkdir .ssh  && chmod 700 .ssh
```

Then change into the newly created directory:

```
    cd .ssh/
```

Here's a refresher on generating a private/public key pair on your local machine:

http://www.ece.uci.edu/~chou/ssh-key.html[1](http://www.ece.uci.edu/~chou/ssh-key.html)

Once you have your id_rsa.pub key, you can cat and then copy the key from your local machine to your server:

```
    echo “paste your_key_here" > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Set permissions on the contents of the directory:

```
    chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
```

It's not a bad idea to edit the SSH config file as a root user (with vi or your text editor of choice):

```
sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and add the users ubuntu foo (and any additional users you've created) to the AllowedUsers Field (you may need to create it if it isn't there):

```
    AllowUsers ubuntu foo
```

(write & quit).

Lastly, restart the service:

```
    service ssh restart
```

Test & confirm that you can now log in as user foo.